# Trying to deploy sp_blitzIndex - but fails

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzindex

I'm trying to deploy the sp_blitzIndex procedure from Brent Ozar. I'm running it in a query window, in SSMS and get the following error:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tempdb..SQLServerCheckup_2A98B846_4179_496B_AAF8_60B405E3ED68_waits'.
Starting run. sp_BlitzIndex(TM) v7.99999 - December 11, 2020

This is being done on the master DB. I'm running SQL Server 2019 developer edition on my local machine.
Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?...2019?

Comment: 2019 (fixed in question)

Comment: Wild guess: case sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to deploy something other than sp_BlitzIndex. The warning that you're getting is part of a paid product that we offer, and I'm guessing that you copy/pasted that script from another source.

Try downloading a fresh copy of sp_BlitzIndex from one of the official sources, like http://firstresponderkit.org or https://www.brentozar.com.

Comment: You are correct. I did pay - I have your toolkit, and am following along one of the pre-recorded trainings. Sounds like I made a bad assumption that the 70_sp_BlitzIndex file from the Consutlant toolkit is actually the BlitzIndex procedure?

Comment: That is indeed a bad assumption. Let's follow the directions rather than getting creative. ;-)